# Automatic document updates in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have 10,000+ couchdb documents, each having (simplified) format like -

```
{
    "First Name" : "John",
    "Last Name" : "Doe"
}
```

I want to add another field to this document, which is e-mail, so that document now looks like -

```
{
    "First Name" : "John",
    "Last Name" : "Doe",
    "e-mail" : ""
}
```

I understand that I can easily update this document by inserting a new JSON, in new format.

But my question is how can I add new field automatically to "all 10,000+" docs that I have existing in the DB? Do I need to write my own script to read each doc and update each one of them individually? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Where will you read email addresses from? Or do you actually want to set them all to blank?

Comment: I want to leave them blank as of now.

Comment: That case should make it easy. If you just add it to the schema and set blank to True, it will have the same effect. I would also set default to "" so it will just work.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, where can one set schema in couchdb? Isn't couchdb a free flowing schema-less DB?

Comment: Yes, it is schema-less, and that is why it smells to me that you "want to leave them blank as of now". What is the difference between blank and undefined here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use views to access your data, you can modify the view without having to modify the documents. Just emit an email value with a default of "".

Assuming the above is no good, use a view to show you which documents need upgrading.

```
function(doc) {
  // views.email_upgrade.map
  if(! ('e-mail' in doc)) {
    var key = [doc["Last Name"], doc["First Name"]];
    emit(key, {_id:doc._id, _rev:doc._rev});
}
```

Query `/db/_design/foo/_view/email_upgrade?include_docs=true`. You can add a `&limit=N` property to help. Query. The `doc` value in each row is a document that needs to upgrade. You can send them back with `POST /db/_bulk_docs`. Loop until you have 0 rows. Once you have 0 rows, add a check to your `validate_doc_update` function.